# Fluent NHibernate hierarchical data

Tags: nhibernate, orm, mapping, fluent

Hey all. Quick question on Fluent syntax.  I had thought I had this down, but I'm getting a weird failure.  Basically, I have a hierarchical kind of structure that I'm trying to persist, and it all seems to work, except when I do an actual integration test w/ the db.

I have a Node object which has a Parent property, which is another Node, and a _children field backing a readonly Children property, which is a collection of Nodes as well.

The properties handle correlating the relationships, and the in-memory objects test out just fine.  When I retrieve them from the repository (an in-memory SQLite db in my tests), though, any Node's Children include itself for some reason.  Any ideas?

My mappings are mostly done w/ AutoMap, but I've overridden the following:

```
mapping.References(x => x.Parent);
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Children).Inverse().Access.LowerCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
```

I've also tried it w/o the Inverse() call.

Comment: hm.  converted the Node class to use a public property w/ get/set instead of the private field and the collection was retrieved correctly.  I'd really prefer to not do it that way, though.

Comment: further info; I check the DB and everything is saving right, the problem is when the data gets pulled back out into objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.  The problem was that I needed to tell the children collection what Id field to hook into for the foreign key.

I changed that mapping to look like so:

```
mapping.HasMany(m => m.Children)
  .Inverse()
  .KeyColumn("ParentId")
  .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
  .Cascade.All()
```

Comment: I had already done it with Castle Framework but I had forgot it and I was battling with your same problem as you. When I read your answer I had a "A-ha" moment, thanks :)